# Android ListView OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, out-of-memory

OK this is a very common problem but mine is a bit different and I can't find solution on other topics, so I post new one here. I have an application which show a ListView. Each row of ListView, I have an ImageView to load a small bitmap icon from SD card using ListAdapter (it's small so the problem is not about the size). Now if I scroll the list slowly, it works fine. But if I scroll really fast, when the ListView is long enough, it's not showing the icon anymore and messages in logcat is something like this:

```
126 600-byte external allocation too large for this process.
```

VM will not let us allocate 126,600 bytes

Then the app crash and logcat showed:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

I tested on 2 different devices and only 1 of them get this error, the other works normally.
Please notice that this error only occurred when the ListView is scrolled very fast. Is that because new threads created is not matched with the pace of garbage collection or something?
Can anybody give me some suggestion in this situation?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: what do you mean by that? I'm really new to android so please be more specific

Comment: While asking on question, please do some search before, there are many questions already been asked here: [**OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=OutOfMemoryError%3A+bitmap+size+exceeds+VM+budget)

Comment: Check for Search box on Right top of your screen.. It will answer you!!

Comment: Of course I've already search other topic, but they don't help, that's why I have to post new one. I said that on my post.

Comment: is that possible to post the code inside getView of ListAdapter?, where you should reuse the view passed and use setTag to keep a reference of the bitmap and recycle the bitmap before set to a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working with bitmap you will mostly get OutOfMemory when used with ListView.

So you should go for [LasyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) as show here.

Will will take care of your image loading.

To work with SDCard you need to replace a method in ImageLoader Class as shown below

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        // If is from SD Card
        try {
            File file = new File(url);
            if(file.exists())
            {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My method is just same as yours and it didn't solve the problem